# How do to get python to not calculate number variable with dash?

Tags: python

I need to pass a variable `'3-123'` to a method in python, but if I do `str(3-123)` I get `'-120'`. Tried iterating, but I got an error cause it's an `int`.

Comment: `str(3-123)` is not a synonym for `"3-123"`.

Comment: To get this clear: your variable is a string?

Comment: I am creating a flask app so 3-123 will be a argument that I need to pass to do a sql query as '3-123'.

Comment: You need to pass as a string not as number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply pass the string `"3-123"`.
Your expression `str(3-123)` tells Python to first evaluate what is in parentheses, which is very clearly the arithmetic expression `3-123`.  That evaluation mandates a subtraction.

UPDATE PER USER COMMENT

Since you just got it returned from REST, then it's already a string.  It seems that your problem is that you're building an expression string to be evaluated in SQL.  In this case, you need to build the string you're going to send to SQL, at the character level.  For this one item you would extend your `3-123` string with quotation marks:

```
from_rest = "3-123"   # In practice, this comes directly from your REST return value.
to_sql = '"' + from_rest + '"'
```

This leaves you with a variable that contains the string `"3-123"` -- seven characters, rather than the original five.

Is that what you needed?

Comment: So my question is how do I convert 3-123 to '3-123' without evaluating it. I am get the value 3-123 from a REST service. I am creating a Flask app that queries SQL Server.

Comment: @Suavp `3-123` must already be in string format.  So you don't need to "convert" it at all.

Comment: What I had to do was similar to what Prune had eluded to 

    assetID = "'" + assetID + "'"

I could then send it to the method that queries SQL Server. You miss the simple stuff when you are deep in the weeds!